# using WHERE on a column that is an array is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, where-clause

I have a table with a column that is an array. There are records in the table that have the array `["something","another thing"]` in the column of `values`. But they are not showing up for some reason when performing a where query. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
# schema
t.text "values", default: "--- []\n"

# model
serialize :values, Array

# rails console
> Table.where(values: ["something","another thing"])
SELECT "tables".* FROM "tables" WHERE "tables"."values" IN ('something', 'another thing')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

So the ideal SQL output I am wanting to create is probably like...

```
SELECT "tables".* FROM "tables" WHERE "tables"."values" = ?  [["values", ["something", "another thing"]]]
```

instead of the `IN` query that the array seems to be creating

Comment: ...WHERE "tables"."values" IN.... should be WHERE tables."values" IN

Comment: @macmuri I've updated the question to include the ideal SQL I an wanting to perform.

Comment: What DB are you usign? if you want it to be an actual array you have to use postgresql, mysql/mariadb does not have an Array column type

Comment: The double quotes on the identifiers on your SQL suggest that you're using PostgreSQL and the YAML in the column suggests that you're using `serialize :values` in the model. So, can you change the schema to replace the `serialize` with an array or JSON column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can agree that it may be inefficient to search through serialized data. 
But here is the solution I came across.

```
# model
scope :matching_values, -> (values) { where(matching_value_query(values, 'AND')) }
scope :subset_of_values, -> (values) { where(matching_value_query(values, 'OR')) }

def self.matching_value_query(values, condition_separator = 'OR')
  values.map { |value| "(values LIKE '%#{value}%')" }.join(" #{condition_separator} ")
end

# rails console
Table.matching_values(["something","another"])
 SELECT "tables".* FROM "tables" WHERE ((values LIKE '%something%') AND (values LIKE '%another%'))
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [ full of stuff ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the column is serialized as an Array, the desired value will be stored as

```
"---\n- something\n- another thing\n"
```

in the database which is a string.

To find such a record via SQL, you will unfortunately have to rely on `LIKE`

```
Table.where(["values LIKE ?", '%something\n- another thing%'])
```

And if there can be other values in between or the order can change, you will also have to take that into account. Please also bear the performance impacts of such a query in mine.

Searching on serialized columns is just something that should not be done.